# I am learning how to properly use Java parameters and arguments

Tags: java

I am learning to use parameters and arguments in Java to make my coding efficient. I am open to suggestion if I've done something wrong with this code of mine.

````
import java.util.Scanner;

public class paramsAndArgs {

    static String name, feeling;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doesSomething(name, feeling);
    }

    private static void doesSomething(String name, String feeling) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How are you today?");
        feeling = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + ". I am feeling " + feeling + " too.");
    }
}
```
````

Comment: There honestly does not seem to be enough code to get much out of a review. LGTM? I'd say post when you have a project with a little bigger scope.

Comment: How about this? https://pastebin.com/WfGrQtdV
It works but it feels kinda wrong to me.

Comment: We can only review the code that is in embedded in the question. You need to show the class and function where this gets used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even with this simple example, there are a few things I can comment on.

1. Class names start with a capital letter.  `ParamsAndArgs`, not `paramsAndArgs`.
2. When parameters are passed to a method, those parameters should have values.  In your code, you're passing the `doSomething` method two parameters that have no values and aren't used in the `doSomething` method.  They're set in the `doSomething` method.
3. While naming a method `doSomething` is okay when you're not sure what the method does, you should change the name to something meaningful, like `getInput`, once you know what the method does. Generally methods are named with a verb, noun combination (get, Input).

Here's your code, reworked to be a more accurate example of parameters and arguments.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParmsAndArgs {

    static String name, feeling;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        getInput(scan);
        System.out.println("Hello, " + name + ". I am feeling " +
                feeling + " too.");
        scan.close();
    }

    private static void getInput(Scanner scan) {
        System.out.println("What is your name?");
        name = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("How are you today?");
        feeling = scan.nextLine();
    }

}
```